# .NET MAUI Blazor Desktop Application | How do I retrieve arguments passed into application

Tags: maui

I have created a brand new .NET MAUI Blazor application using the standard template. There is a Program.cs file that has been created. As the title suggests, how do I retrieve arguments passed into application using C#?

Comment: I can't understand what you want clearly. Could you please show more details?

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT Winforms equivalent: "Application.Run(new FrmMain(args));"

Comment: But there is no Form in the maui. Did you want to show the ContentPage or the Windows or the RazorPage?

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT I added a few other details to the question including a pic of debug profile.

Comment: I can't see the information you added.